# var=output of command, then perform operation on var

Tags: shell

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5LS3.png) I want to use var to execute command using a lot usernames in the output of a command stored as var. The code i have written is:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=`finger -lmps @10.10.10.10 | cut -f1 | tail -n+2`
for Username in "$var"
do
      finger -lmps $Username@10.10.10.10
done
```

I've got error saying 'finger: invalid option -- "-"'. The output of echo var isn't in columns its more like a paragraph, from which i have to pick strings like alice, carol  etc to use them as usernames.

Is there a way to save var as a file then use usernames from that to use in for loop?

Comment: Use backticks or `$(...)`?  `var=\`finger -lmps @10.10.10.10\``.

Comment: Sorry! forgot to add them here, any idea about rest of the stuff?

Comment: What you've written seems like it should work, assuming the first `finger` command outputs a list of usernames separated by whitespace, except that `var` on the second line should be `$var`.  What is your question?

Comment: I've updated the code, but i get error saying var not found.

Comment: The second `finger` should not be in backticks.  That will take whatever string the remote server returns and execute it as a command.  Very dangerous.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. But will it execute without backticks?

Comment: The finger command will execute, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finger -lmps @10.10.10.10 > tmpfile 
grep -v -- --- tmpfile | grep -o ^[a-z]*
```

What is the output now?

Comment: This actually gave error saying 'finger: invalid option -- "-" '

Comment: I've added echo of var in the main question, if that clearifies it more, because the output isn't in columns its more like a paragraph, from which i have to pick strings like alice, carol  etc to use them as usernames

Comment: i also stumbled upon cut command, but still 'finger: invalid option -- "-" ' error after updating.

Comment: try with awk, it's more resilient to the field separator. I've edited again

Comment: awk line 1: syntac error at or near point, must be due ------ line i guess.

Comment: You can get rid of that line with sed, but the awk should have worked. I'll edit again

Comment: No, that didn't work either, Can i take the output command from var save it to a file then use usernames from there?

Comment: the output has the dashes removed and still is in column format and has all the columns, added image in the main ques

Comment: What about now?

Comment: same output as before

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, try it again pease

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after = . This is not allowed in bash and others.

```
var='finger -lmps @10.10.10.10'
for Username in $($var)
```

I think you want to run the var statement too

Comment: I tried that but the error still says var not found.

Comment: what script do you use ? bash ? sh ?

Comment: yes, i want to run var statement first then it outputs several columns Username Login etc and a lot of results, i want to traverse through every user.

Comment: try now again please, changed in the answer

Comment: change $(var) to ($var) please

Comment: I copy pasted the code from here, Now it says "(" expected.

Comment: sorry :) forgot the $ in front . is `for Username in $($var) `

Comment: sorry it didn't work either, i've added more info to the question